# Simple way to get UTF input using JavaScript+DOM alone?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, utf-8

Is there a simple way to get UTF character input on keypress on the browser, using JavaScript+DOM alone?

I've tried the following:

```
            key_capturer = document.createElement("textarea");
            key_capturer.style.position = "absolute";
            key_capturer.style.left = "-100px";
            key_capturer.style.right = "-100px";
            key_capturer.style.width = "100px";
            key_capturer.style.height = "100px";
            key_capturer.focus();
            key_capturer.onblur = function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    key_capturer.focus();
                },0);
            };
            key_capturer.onkeydown = function(a){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var input = key_capturer.value;
                    if (input.length>0){
                        key_capturer.value = "";
                        /* DO SOMETHING WITH INPUT HERE */
                    };
                },0);
            };
            document.body.appendChild(key_capturer);
```

Which works by creating a hidden textarea, waiting for keydown event, reading the content of that textarea and emptying it. It is not elegant because it must be always focused. I guess there should be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the best way to do it. Like a lot of front-end development, you need a hacky solution.

Don't try and use the character code with `String.fromCharCode()` as it wasn't designed for transfer into the typed character.

I'm pretty certain from my own exploration that many other web applications do this, including Google Docs (but that may have changed since I last digged into it).

Comment: @Viclib You could always get the focused element (if any) and store what it was, focus your hidden input and then put focus back onto the previous input.